# Python class return values

Tags: python, function, class

I write a program to get and return values from the python class function. But Val function returns 0s. Please help me to fix it

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, temp=0, hum=0, ppm=0):
        self.temp = temp
        self.hum = hum
        self.ppm = ppm
        myMQTTClient.subscribe("test", 1, self.customCallback)

    def customCallback(self, client, userdata, message):
        data = json.loads((message.payload).decode("utf-8"))
        self.temp = data["Temperature"]
        self.hum = data["Humidity"]
        self.ppm = data["Particulate count"]
        print(self.temp, self.hum, self.ppm)
    
    def val(self):
        print(self.temp, self.hum, self.ppm)
        return[self.temp, self.hum, self.ppm]
        
bar = Foo()
print(bar.val())
```

I got output like this

```
10 20 30

0 0 0

[0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: What output are you expecting? You initialize those attributes to 0 in `__int__` and then return them from `val()`. This works exactly as I'd expect.

Comment: I want to return 10 20 30 from the val function

Comment: Where does the callback happen where the `customCallback` function is called?

Comment: try this:
bar = Foo(temp=10, hum=20, ppm=30)

Comment: customCallback is call from AWSIoTPythonSDK lib